# Is there any way for a player character to automatically pass a saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw

Many monsters have the following ability:

> *Legendary Resistance* (x/day). If the [monster] fails a saving throw, it can choose to succeed instead.

This ability allows the monster to pass any saving throw, *regardless of DC*.

Player characters, on the other hand, have many abilities which allow them to increase their  likelihood of passing a saving throw: examples include Indomitable, Dark One's Blessing, and so forth. To my knowledge, however, none of these abilities provide a means of unconditionally passing a saving throw.

Besides using an effect like Polymorph which replaces a player character's stat sheet with that of a monster, do player characters have any options which provide them with the ability to automatically pass a saving throw, regardless of its DC?

Comment: I take it you would want this option to be applicable to *any* saving throw, or would options that only apply to certain subsets work?

Comment: @Medix2 something that let's you pass *any* saving throw is better, but a subset of saving throws definitely makes a valid answer as well.

Answer (score 7):

The Chronurgy Wizard's 14-th level ability lets you (or someone else) unconditionally succeed a saving throw, at the cost of a reaction and a level of exhaustion:

> **Convergent Future**
> Starting at 14th level, you can peer through possible futures and magically pull one of them into events around you, ensuring a particular outcome. When you or a creature you can see within 60 feet of you makes an attack roll, an ability check, or a saving throw, you can use your reaction to ignore the die roll and decide whether the number rolled is the minimum needed to succeed or one less than that number (your choice).
> When you use this feature, you gain one level of exhaustion. Only by finishing a long rest can you remove a level of exhaustion gained in this way.

Under my interpretation of this ability, this can make you succeed on saving throws even if you would not succeed by rolling a 20, but that interpretation of the ability does not seem to be universal, so whether or not this ability can do that would be up to your DM's interpretation.

Comment: Can this ability be used to roll higher than what is possible?  That is, if the minimum number needed to succeed was a 21, would this ability let you 'roll' that?

Comment: To me, that seems to be the only reasonable way to read this ability, but it seems like there's not a lot of consensus on how this ability actually works.

Comment: @Kirt [We have a whole question on specifically that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/166625). The main answer there seems to say that if the number needed to roll is a 21, you simply do not roll at all so the feature could not be used. That said, there are times where how much you fail by matters, so I'm unsure how well that answer works.

Comment: Considering that this feature doesn't provide the ability to succeed on any saving throw *regardless of DC* I unfortunately can't accept this answer. Nonetheless this is a great example of something that works in most cases so I'm happy to give it an upvote, however I would ask that you add a disclaimer linking to the post mentioned by Medix2.

Comment: Your interpretation opposes the part of the feature that says *"peer through **possible** futures"*, emphasis mine.

Comment: I see why you think that, and I would be happy to further justify why I think my interpretation is correct, but I think I have enough to say about that I will probably write it up as my own answer to the linked question on the topic.